# dependency problems prevent configuration

Tags: dependencies

I've gotten my Ubuntu server into an inconsistent state.  I've read through a thread on a similar issue but am still unsure how best to proceed.

Here is some info:

```
# dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
# uname -r
3.2.0-60-generic
```

By way of background, I found the /boot partition was full and was attempting to clean up when I began getting errors.  Initially the kernel level was `3.2.0-44-generic` but my upgrade attempts brought in newer files and unfortunately the /boot partition filled up again in the middle of upgrading.

Now I get the following:

```
#apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-39-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-34 linux-headers-3.2.0-40 linux-headers-3.2.0-41 linux-headers-3.2.0-43
  linux-headers-3.2.0-38 linux-headers-3.2.0-39 linux-headers-3.2.0-34-generic linux-image-3.2.0-40-generic linux-image-3.2.0-43-generic
  linux-headers-3.2.0-40-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-43-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-38-generic linux-image-3.2.0-41-generic
  linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-41-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-server
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-server
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 159 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,734 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-server:
 linux-server depends on linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.45.54); however:
  Version of linux-image-server on system is 3.2.0.60.71.
 linux-server depends on linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.45.54); however:
  Version of linux-headers-server on system is 3.2.0.60.71.
dpkg: error processing linux-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Based on the prior solution I read about, I may need to manually download and install files, I'm just not sure which ones.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloaded and installed older versions of linux-image-server and linux-headers-server.  Was then able to reinstall linux-server.  After that apt-get worked.

```
$ wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/linux-image-server_3.2.0.45.54_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i linux-image-server_3.2.0.45.54_*.deb
$ wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/linux-headers-server_3.2.0.45.54_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-server_3.2.0.45.54_*.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i linux-server_3.2.0.45.54_*.deb
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```